# Internship at Danetrack in west hollywood

Tags: internships, sound-design

Has anyone done an internship at Danetrack? How was it? Did you get to work with sound designer Dane Davis a lot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent about 4 months or so interning at DaneTracks. You definitely have the opportunity to watch excellent people work who are at the top of their game and ask them questions. DaneTracks was handling *Speed Racer* and *The Incredible Hulk* at the time and I was able to sit in on the mix at Warner Brothers a few times which was really cool. I got some great advice about recording field FX from one of the editors, which was extremely helpful.

On the other hand, there was a lot of busywork to be done like cleaning up the facility, assisting the DaneTracks manager with clerical stuff and making coffee. The ratio of useful and interesting stuff to mindless busywork was too low for me, which is why I decided to leave.

If you're still starting out with ProTools, field recording, post sound work flow and the big ideas of sound design, this is a great internship. You can learn a lot and make some good connections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to intern there as well, as all of my internships have been in the commercial world.  I know a few people that did this internship and strongly recommend it.

Get your information in as soon as possible.  They keep applications in order and when they need an intern, they go to the next one in line.  First come, first serve.